# Magento 2, How to call front controller from admin page?

Tags: admin, magento2.2, controllers, pdf

Using `magento 2`, `front and admin`, I need to access controller in `print button` on sale order page to print invoice which generate pdf in front view controller. Plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do that, I am sure using redirect to your front end controller should be worked.

```
public function getPrintUrl()
{
    $baseUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getBaseUrl();
    return $baseUrl.'/order/printpdf/invoice_id/'.$this->getInvoice()->getId();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: You save my day.